# Why do you need lambda to nest defaultdict?

Tags: python, lambda, defaultdict

I am a bit confused on why you need a lambda function for nesting defaultdict

Why can't you do it like this?

```
test = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))
```

instead of

```
test = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(float))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
test = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))
```

Because `defaultdict` requires that you give it something that can be *called* to create keys for missing values. `list` is such a callable, but `defaultdict(list)` is not. It's a `defaultdict` instance, and you can't call a `defaultdict`.

The `lambda` is a function that, when called, *returns* a value that can be used in the dictionary, so it works.

Essentially, `defaultdict(list)` is going to be evaluated *before* your `defaultdict` is instantiated, and you want to *defer* that until a missing key is encountered. This is why a callable object (a type or a function) is used here.

Comment: The analog for `list` being, of course, `lambda: list()`.